# MVP in GWT. Complicated Views

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

Have a question about using mvp on complicated views.
Suppose, we have some widget with boilerplate design (ListWidget) like this:
[image]

Control buttons provide functionality for switching between ContentPanel (just regular CellTable with data) and DetailsPanel (here we can edit particular entry, this is not Modal Dialog)

DetailsPanel, in turn, have this structure
[image]

Button1, Button2, Button3 should deal only with DetailsPanel and change ActionPanel (ActionPanel some kind of wizard, so its content should be tottaly changed after Button1, Button2 or Button3 clicked), but Buttons Save and Cancel should navigate us back onto ListWidget.

1. What approach should I use to implement described functionality?
2. Should I use 2 different ActivityManagers with one of them in master context or not?
3. How to manage and broadcast messages to dependant panels on ListWidget? (Is it ok to put Handlers in Views and just push event into inner eventBus on some actions?
   For instance, when I save item in DetailsPanel, PreviewPanel should change and this item should be focused in CellTable; etc)
4. If I should use pattern with two different ActivityManagers, how exactly should I handle activity change behavior?

Thanks, hope somebody helps me.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/2812e1b15a2a98a6?hl=de
maybe it will help somebody

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, please feel free to do so! However, please at least explain the point of the linked text (if the link breaks, so does the answer unless context is provided).

Answer (score 1):

I am answering your question, first with a brief explanation and then point by point taking your questions.

At framework level, you could have a class which implements `ValueChangeHandler` and set that on History using `History.addValueChangeHandler(controller);` assuming controller is implementing the value change handler

Any newItem you would put in history with `History.newItem("NameOfAction")` would invoke implementation of `ValueChangeHandler` which in this case would be `controller`
Now within implementation of `ValueChangeHandler` you can

```
String token = event.getValue();
if (token.equals("NameOfAction")) {
    Call Appropriate presenter
}
```

Now let's talk about the second part of framework, presenter and view implementation. I am assuming that RootPanel is the container of all your UI Widgets. You can create individual presenters for each action

`presenter = new ActionPresenter(rpc, eventbus, new ActionView())`

Notice that I am creating a view and passing on to the presenter, presenter gets data and build the view with data. You could later pass on the container to the presenter to show the whole thing on UI.

Now about your specific questions

1. MVP would be your best bet here The article on MVP [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html) is pretty good
2. I don't see a reason to use 2 activity managers as long as your container of those widgets is same
3. EventBus would be ideal. If you have to pass data with events, session variable like static fields in main class would server your purpose
4. I would need more details on exactly what you want to put in which manager

Hope this helps!